# Plotting over inner or outer "loop" of a data structure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I often organise my data in lists of dictionaries. The example below shows storing two types of line graphs, of a quadratic and a linear type, each with different constants. The way my data is organised currently makes it easy to plot the effect of changing the constants for each type of graph class. However what if I wanted to plot the effect of the graph type for a fixed constant? In other words I would have 4 figures with two lines in each. I must make due with how the `data` is organised and therefore can't rewrite the creation of that data structure. Any ideas for a clean pythonic way to do this?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 


x = np.linspace(-1,1,20)

y1 = lambda x,c : x+c 
y2 = lambda x,c : c*np.power(x,2)

y1(x,1)
y2(x,2)


# Create data structure 
keys = ["quad", "lin"]
const = [1,2,3,4]
data = {}

for key in keys:
    data[key] = []
    for c in const:
        graph = {}

        graph["x"] = x 
        if key == "lin":
            graph["y"] = y1(x,c) 
        if key == "quad":
            graph["y"] = y2(x,c) 
        data[key].append(graph)





# Plots for same line type
for key,graphs in data.iteritems():
    plt.figure()
    for g in graphs:
        plt.plot(g["x"],g["y"])


plt.show()
```

[image]
[image]

What I want is to loop through the `c` values on the outer plotting loop so that the effect is:

```
# Plots for same constant 
plt.figure()
plt.plot(data["quad"][0]['x'],data["quad"][0]['y'])
plt.plot(data["lin"][0]['x'],data["lin"][0]['y'])

plt.figure()
plt.plot(data["quad"][1]['x'],data["quad"][1]['y'])
plt.plot(data["lin"][1]['x'],data["lin"][1]['y'])

plt.figure()
plt.plot(data["quad"][2]['x'],data["quad"][2]['y'])
plt.plot(data["lin"][2]['x'],data["lin"][2]['y'])

plt.figure()
plt.plot(data["quad"][3]['x'],data["quad"][3]['y'])
plt.plot(data["lin"][3]['x'],data["lin"][3]['y'])
```

but rather explicitly writing this out for each index of `const` I want to loop.

Comment: I have tried to update with what the intended effect should be. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you simply want to exchange the two loops,

```
for c in range(len(const)):
    plt.figure()
    for k in keys:
        plt.plot(data[k][c]['x'],data[k][c]['y'])
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Here is a neat approach(imo) to solve what you are doing: You can make a sort of id by combining the graph-type and const: `lin1`, `lin2`... `quad4`, etc. For the values you can either use map or a list comprehension (I have used list comprehension, below). So basically `data` will be `dict` object with several lists in it(which in turn are lists of `[x_values, y_values]` for each curve). You can then iterate with the same primary ids `lin1, quad4, etc` and draw the plots using plt.show().

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 


x = np.linspace(-1,1,20)

y1 = lambda x,c : x+c 
y2 = lambda x,c : c*np.power(x,2)

y1(x,1)
y2(x,2)

# Create data structure 
keys = ["quad", "lin"]
const = [1,2,3,4]
data = {}

for key in keys:
    for num in const:
        data[key+str(num)]=[x,[[y1,y2][key=="lin"](e,num) for e in x]]

# Plots for same line type
for i in keys:
    plt.figure()
    for j in const:
        plt.plot(x,data[i+str(j)][1])
    plt.show()
```

If you want 4 different plots for the same constant, just use this:

```
for j in const:
    plt.figure()
    for i in keys:
        plt.plot(x,data[i+str(j)][1])
    plt.show()
```